# Any sample codes for uploading file in Android Eclipse using Intent

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent

I'm new to Android application development and I'm using Eclipse.
there's one thing I want to ask, how can files be uploaded to my database?
can you give me sample codes that will help me understand the use of intent?

Answer (score 1):

It's not dead simple. First of all it depends on the database. If it's MySQL you need to make one `POST` or `GET` request to a php script. The php script then handles saving the files to the database.

For how to connect to the internet please see: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

Answer (score 0):

**You should go to android example there is full working project for upload file to your server:
use below link:**

http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106

**You also need to upload php script to your server via ftp before using it.Php script look like this:**

```
<?php

$file_path = "uploads/";

$file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
    echo "success";
} else{
    echo "fail";
}
?>
```